# xvfb-run aborting on cluster

Tags: ssh, x11, xvfb, slurm

I'm trying to run a python script with `xvfb-run` on a cluster using SLURM; when I use an interactive session (`srun`) it works fine, but when submitting to a queue (`sbatch`) it aborts/fails without much information.

```
/usr/bin/xvfb-run: line 166: 34566 Aborted                 DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1
```

in `/usr/bin/xvfb-run`:

```
...
164: # Start the command and save its exit status.                                                                                                                                                             
165: set +e
166: DISPLAY=:$SERVERNUM XAUTHORITY=$AUTHFILE "$@" 2>&1
167: RETVAL=$?
168: set -e
...
```

any ideas why this would fail?  I've tried specifying my .Xauthority file, but that doesn't help, i.e.

```
xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" -f ~/.Xauthority python DrawStreams.py
```

The problem does **not** occur if I just print out the `env` (i.e. if I replace 'python DrawStreams.py' with 'env').  So its some sort of combination of the job queue, xvfb-run, **and** python all together...

Comment: Do you rember if you managed to solve it? a similar issue.